# How to collapse a table for mobile views

Tags: css, vue.js, vuejs3

I currently have a table (Built in vue with Quasar) that looks like this

[image: Table1]

When on a mobile view I would like to collapse it to this:

[image: Table2]

I've done some looking around and tried setting everything to display:Block but the text then starts overflowing etc...

I am using vue so can utilise that if needed, doesnt need to be a pure css solution

Codepen of current HTML: https://codepen.io/Olemus/pen/WNzoppL (note that this is taken directly from the DOM and is not my vue components etc)

```
<tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a bootstrap-like css solution, where the table is all there and you just need to scroll: [table example](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/content/tables/#always-responsive)
Or if you don't need those cells you could use Vue, creare a variable `isMobile` that becomes `true` when under a certain width, and simply apply a `v-if="!isMobile"` on the cells/rows you need. 
And since you are using vue 3, there's already a composable for that in a library called `vueuse`: [useMediaQuery](https://vueuse.org/core/usemediaquery/#usemediaquery)